# Batch file manipulate csv and import with mysql

Tags: mysql, windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to import a `CSV` to `mySQL` using `Batch script`. The part that imports the `csv` to `mysql` works but if the `csv` file contains empty fields (like apple,banana,,kiwi) then it doesn't work correctly.

So what I am trying to do is to manipulate the csv file beforehand in order to replace `,,` with `, ,` . I tried to find some code online in order to achieve that because it is my first `Batch script` but it doesn't work.

Here is my `Batch script`:

```
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "search=,,"
    set "replace=, ,"

    set "textFile=eform.csv"

    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )
@echo on
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p kepdb_db < infile.sql
pause
```

If this script worked and then if the csv file contains 3 consecutive empty fields -> `apple,,,,banana` then it would be converted to -> `apple, , , ,banana` or `apple, ,, ,banana` ??

Comment: Don't use a [tag:batch-file] to try to manipulate the content of CSV files, instead use a scripting language which has built in support for such things, [tag:powershell] for instance.

Comment: @Compo how can I achieve that using powershell?

Comment: By writing some powershell code based upon previous similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the line:

```cmd
set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
```

just before the line:

```cmd
>>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
```

Since the used [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) functionality scans the string from left to right to do the replacements, already handled characters do not be involved in further replacements. Hence `,,,` becomes `, ,,` as the second `,` has already been handled by the former replacement, so the third one stands alone. For the same reason `,,,,` becomes `, ,, ,`, and so on. Therefore you must do a second scan and replacement.

Note that this may produce unexpected results when any field value contains sequences of `,` on their own (which is possible when the value is quoted, like `apple,"ora,,nge",,,banana`; this would become modified to `apple,"ora, ,nge", , ,banana` since quotation is not regarded, although `apple,"ora,,nge", , ,banana` would be correct).